# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException Error

Tags: android, kotlin

New to Android development. I haven't started working on my project and its already throwing out errors.
I've started this thread after going through the rest (none of the solutions worked for me). I'm having trouble finding the ClassCastException. I've only selected the menu as the default template and was trying out Google Admobs

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
     lateinit var mAdView : AdView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Google Ad-mobs Code
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        MobileAds.initialize(this)
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
   // Code for the menu
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
    Process: com.albertjokelin.revise, PID: 10460
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.albertjokelin.revise.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.albertjokelin.revise.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.albertjokelin.revise.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1148)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-04-18 11:12:28.865 10460-10460/com.albertjokelin.revise I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10460 SIG: 9
```

One of the answers told that I've been converting an object of one class to another. But I don't see where I'm making the error. (Sorry just a noob)

Comment: You are missing part of the stack trace, notably the details of the error message and the line where it occurs.

Comment: My guess is some of those findViewById are failing because you use the wrong type, debug it and you will figure it out.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the entire logcat

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have this (or equivalent):

```
<application
        android:name="com.albertjokelin.revise.MainActivity"
        ...
```

If you remove the attribute

```
android:name="com.albertjokelin.revise.MainActivity"
```

you will get rid of the crash. It crashes because it tries to instantiate your MainActivity as the application object since you erroneously declared it should do that.

Since you say you are a noob I'm going to assume you have not read the following documentation on this topic, so please make sure to do that :) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro